# Split string with multiple separators from an array (Python)

Tags: python, split, delimiter

Given an array of separators:

```
columns = ["Name:", "ID:", "Date:", "Building:", "Room:", "Notes:"]
```

and a string where some columns were left blank (and there is random white space):

```
input = "Name:      JohnID:123:45Date:  8/2/17Building:Room:Notes:  i love notes"
```

How can I get this:

```
["John", "123:45", "8/2/17", "", "", "i love notes"]
```

I've tried simply removing the substrings to see where I can go from there but I'm still stuck

```
import re
input = re.sub(r'|'.join(map(re.escape, columns)), "", input)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the list to generate a regular expression by inserting `(.*)` in between, then use `strip` to remove spaces:

```
import re

columns = ["Name:", "ID:", "Date:", "Building:", "Room:", "Notes:"]
s = "Name:      JohnID:123:45Date:  8/2/17Building:Room:Notes:  i love notes"

result = [x.strip() for x in re.match("".join(map("{}(.*)".format,columns)),s).groups()]

print(result)
```

yields:

```
['John', '123:45', '8/2/17', '', '', 'i love notes']
```

the `strip` part can be handled by the regular expression at the expense of a more complex regex, but simpler overall expression:

```
result = re.match("".join(map("{}\s*(.*)\s*".format,columns)),s).groups()
```

more complex: if field data contains regex special chars, we have to escape them (not the case here):

```
result = re.match("".join(["{}\s*(.*)\s*".format(re.escape(x)) for x in columns]),s).groups()
```

Comment: For some reason I am getting `['John', '123:45', '8/2/17', '', '', '']`

Comment: edited, the greedy mode caused problems apparently. Now fixed.

Answer (score 4):

How about using [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split)?

```
>>> import re
>>> columns = ["Name:", "ID:", "Date:", "Building:", "Room:", "Notes:"]
>>> i = "Name:      JohnID:123:45Date:  8/2/17Building:Room:Notes:  i love notes"
>>> re.split('|'.join(map(re.escape, columns)), i)
['', '      John', '123:45', '  8/2/17', '', '', '  i love notes']
```

To get rid of the whitespace, split on whitespace too:

```
>>> re.split(r'\s*' + (r'\s*|\s*'.join(map(re.escape, columns))) + r'\s*', i.strip())
['', 'John', '123:45', '8/2/17', '', '', '  i love notes']
```

Comment: good, and probably what OP had in mind. But issues an empty field at start.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The empty field at the start is because you split by the value `"Name:"`. There is nothing to the left of that, so it makes an empty string. There could be something to the left.